# Write tenor and alto sax Score along piano

Tags: notation, sheet-music, saxophone, transposition

please ! someone help me understand this.

I am writing a score for piano and tenor sax in C Major, simple.

Now, how do you write the music on the sheet for both instruments

[image]

In this example, is the Sax player going to play his C ( Which is a concert Bb ) ? or does he/she has to transpose this note to the sax note in his/her head ?

Thanks, any hints or help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's ambiguous. I can easily opt to interpret all instruments as being in concert pitch notation, so the tenor sax part is in concert C Major and the sax player will have to do all the transposing themselves mentally.

Comment: I think 'alto' needs removing from this question, as that requires a different answer.

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of transposing instruments is that they, well, transpose. A B♭ sax is so-called because when the player sees a note, and plays it, it comes out a tone below what is written.

In order to compensate for this, the music needs to be written **one tone** *higher* than what would be played. So in your case, for the sax player to produce a C note, you'd write a D.

Comment: Thank you @Tim, got it, ... following this train of thought ... if I want the Sax player to produce an **E** then I have to write a **F#**, so my following question is: should I just put the Sax pentagram in D Mayor instead of writing F# and C# (for the concert B) all over the place ?

Comment: Yes, that's what should happen. Piano in key C, sax in key D (written). Don't understand '(for the concert B)' bit.

Comment: It is also customary to put the solo instrument line above the piano part. It is easier for the accompanist to follow the soloist's part this way.

Comment: @HeatherS. - true - as opposed to the stave shown in the question.

Comment: @Tim, I figured I would tag it onto your good answer, even though it didn't directly relate to the OP's question.